# Session.getActiveSession() returns null when starting the app, although I'm connected

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I use com.facebook.widget.UserSettingsFragment to manage login/logout to Facebook in my app:

```
UserSettingsFragment userSettingsFragment = new UserSettingsFragment();
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
if(session==null || session.isClosed()){
    userSettingsFragment.setPublishPermissions(Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
}
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_container, userSettingsFragment, "userSettingsFragment");
```

In another `Fragment` (but same `Activity`), Before publishing on Facebook I'm checking whether I'm logged using

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
if (session != null && session.isOpened()){
    publishOnFacebook(intent.getExtras());
}
```

When I start my app and try to publish, I always get a `null` `Session` although I logged in before. And when I start `UserSettingsFragment`, it shows me that I'm connected.

How can `Session.getActiveSession();` be `null` if I'm actually connected?

Moreover, if I I start the `Fragment` where I do the publishing straight after `UserSettingsFragment`, I get the correct `Session`, i.e.:

```
1 start the app
2 call `Session.getActiveSession()` in another `Fragment` returns `null`
3 start `UserSettingsFragment` shows that I'm log
```

but

```
1 start the app
2 start `UserSettingsFragment` shows that I'm log
3 call `Session.getActiveSession()` in another `Fragment` returns a session
```

Anybody can help?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Ok, I've just read about `openActiveSessionFromCache` (not from Facebook doc though):

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession(); 

if(session==null){                      
    // try to restore from cache
    session = Session.openActiveSessionFromCache(getActivity());
}

if(session!=null && session.isOpened()){    
    publishOnFacebook(intent.getExtras());  
}
else{
    login();
}
```

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument '148885915321893' cannot be null
Getting this exception while trying 'Session.getActiveSession(); '

Comment: This isn't working. I linked my app from the Prefs Activity and now i am trying to get the Session on Sharing Activity and The Session is always returning null.

Answer (score 0):

Jul's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18296806/3446669) does not work for me. So I tried this:

If you had loggedin earlier and if you restarted the app then the session may not be null and it could be in the CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED state. This state implies that the Session has not yet been opened and has a cached token. Opening a Session in this state will not involve user interaction. To open the session from this state you can call the method session.openForRead(null). This immediately opens the session without any user interaction.

So check for this add the following code:

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
if (session != null){
    if(session.getState() == SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED){
        //this immediately opens the session
        session.openForRead(null);
    }
    if(session.isOpened()) {
        publishOnFacebook(intent.getExtras());
    }
    else{
        //start the facebook login fragment or activity
        login();
    }
}
else{
    login();
}
```