# Facebook Login crashes java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, android, facebook, android-facebook

I am trying to integrate the Facebook login into my app.
The user logins in with Facebook and the app then gets the users email address which gets passed to my apps login system (accounts are stored on a remote mysql database).
I have the below code:

```
public class FbLoginActivity extends Activity {

    private static List<String> permissions;
    Session.StatusCallback statusCallback = new SessionStatusCallback();
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fblogin);
        Button fbButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fbshare);
        /***** FB Permissions *****/
        permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
        permissions.add("email");
        /***** End FB Permissions *****/
        fbButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Check if there is any Active Session, otherwise Open New
                // Session
                Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
                if (!session.isOpened()) {
                    session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(
                            FbLoginActivity.this).setCallback(statusCallback)
                            .setPermissions(permissions));
                } else {
                    Session.openActiveSession(FbLoginActivity.this, true,
                            statusCallback);
                }
            }
        });
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session == null) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                session = Session.restoreSession(this, null, statusCallback,
                        savedInstanceState);
            }
            if (session == null) {
                session = new Session(this);
            }
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            session.addCallback(statusCallback);
            if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) {
                session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(this).setCallback(
                        statusCallback).setPermissions(permissions));
            }
        }
    }

    private class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {

        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            // Check if Session is Opened or not
            processSessionStatus(session, state, exception);
        }
    }

    public void processSessionStatus(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
            if (session.getPermissions().contains("email")) {
                // Show Progress Dialog
                dialog = new ProgressDialog(FbLoginActivity.this);
                dialog.setMessage("Logging in..");
                dialog.show();
                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,
                        new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCompleted(GraphUser user,
                                    Response response) {

                                if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                                if (user != null) {
                                    Map<String, Object> responseMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                                    GraphObject graphObject = response
                                            .getGraphObject();
                                    responseMap = graphObject.asMap();
                                    Log.i("FbLogin", "Response Map KeySet - "
                                            + responseMap.keySet());
                                    // TODO : Get Email
                                    // responseMap.get("email");
                                    String fb_id = user.getId();
                                    String email = null;
                                    String name = (String) responseMap
                                            .get("name");
                                    if (responseMap.get("email") != null) {
                                        email = responseMap.get("email")
                                                .toString();
                                        Intent i = new Intent(FbLoginActivity.this, FbLogin2Activity.class);
                                        i.putExtra("Email", email);
                                        startActivity(i);
                                    } else {
                                        // Clear all session info & ask user to
                                        // login again
                                        Session session = Session
                                                .getActiveSession();
                                        if (session != null) {
                                            session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
            } else {
                session.requestNewReadPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(
                        FbLoginActivity.this, permissions));
            }
        }
    }

    /********** Activity Methods **********/
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d("FbLogin", "Result Code is - " + resultCode + "");
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(FbLoginActivity.this,
                requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // TODO Save current session
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        Session.saveSession(session, outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Add status callback
        super.onStart();
        Session.getActiveSession().addCallback(statusCallback);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Remove callback
        super.onStop();
        Session.getActiveSession().removeCallback(statusCallback);
    }
}
```

I then get the below error

```
09-12 15:28:07.728: E/AndroidRuntime(30897): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-12 15:28:07.728: E/AndroidRuntime(30897): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Session: an attempt was made to open an already opened session.
09-12 15:28:07.728: E/AndroidRuntime(30897):    at com.facebook.Session.open(Session.java:947)
09-12 15:28:07.728: E/AndroidRuntime(30897):    at com.facebook.Session.openForRead(Session.java:385)
09-12 15:28:07.728: E/AndroidRuntime(30897):    at com.test.app.FbLoginActivity$1.onClick(FbLoginActivity.java:48)
09-12 15:28:07.728: E/AndroidRuntime(30897):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4278)
09-12 15:28:07.728: E/AndroidRuntime(30897):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17430)
09-12 15:28:07.728: E/AndroidRuntime(30897):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
09-12 15:28:07.728: E/AndroidRuntime(30897):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-12 15:28:07.728: E/AndroidRuntime(30897):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:213)
09-12 15:28:07.728: E/AndroidRuntime(30897):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5092)
09-12 15:28:07.728: E/AndroidRuntime(30897):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-12 15:28:07.728: E/AndroidRuntime(30897):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-12 15:28:07.728: E/AndroidRuntime(30897):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
09-12 15:28:07.728: E/AndroidRuntime(30897):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:564)
09-12 15:28:07.728: E/AndroidRuntime(30897):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

However some times it works fine on some devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your fbButton's onClick listener, you have:

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
if (!session.isOpened()) {
    session.openForRead(...);
} else {
    Session.openActiveSession(...);
}
```

But in your else clause, the session is already opened, so you don't need to open it again. Instead, what you should do is:

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
if (session == null) {
    Session.openActiveSession(...);
} else if (!session.isOpened()) {
    session.openForRead(...);
}
```

Comment: Hi, if session is already opened, how could I add a 'publish_stream' permission with openForPublish() method?

Answer (score 0):

It's saying an attempt was made to open an already opened session so you're trying to reopen an already opened session somewhere. It could be to do with a cached session. You could have a look at this link:
[Session.getActiveSession() returns null when starting the app, although I'm connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18295998/session-getactivesession-returns-null-when-starting-the-app-although-im-conn)